# Setting 1x1 px image as background image of UIButton not rendering correctly in IB

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, interface-builder

When configuring a button in IB, I set background image of this button with a 1x1 px image. Since the button has no background color and the color of button title is white, the button is invisible in IB. But it is rendered correctly when running with the tiled image. This issue makes me a little inconvenient when working in IB. The version of Xcode is 7.2. Is it a bug of Xcode? Is there any workaround?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you use backgroundColor?One pixel image makes no difference.

Comment: @Lumialxk backgroundColor does not work well with different states of button. When state is UIControlStateNormal I use a color and UIControlStateHighlighted is another color. This can be done in code with [UIButton setBackgroundImage:forState:] API, and also in IB. I want to do this in IB. Bigger size images do not have this issue

Comment: Why not extend UIButton?You can draw a image from a color.Actually,this is more effective.

Comment: @Lumialxk I did that before. But since it can be done in IB, I prefer doing stuff like this in IB because I can see the result immediately. For performance, I don't think there is much difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see,I found you set the image but not background so you can't see it.[image]

Check images,are there all resolutions ready?In my storyboard,it works.

[image]

Comment: Set image is OK at run time but the image will keep its size unless you set the frame fixed.

Comment: Using a bigger sized image do not have this issue.

Comment: Try using a bigger size image as the background image, you can see it can be rendered in IB.

Comment: OK, I figured out. Turns out it's because I put the 1px image to the 2x image set. After putting it to 1x image set, it works. Edit your answer, I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.